# What SQL command I can use to get p50 from a set of data group by a key?

Tags: sql

What SQL command I can use to get p50 from a set of data group by a key?

Example data set:

```
 date   count
---------------
2023-01-01  10
2023-01-01  17
2023-01-01  20
2023-02-01  13
2023-02-01  13
2023-02-01  14

Intended Results

date      p50
---------------    
2023-01-01  17
2023-02-01  13
```

Tried

```sql
select date, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by count asc) as p50
FROM tablename 
group by date
```

Failed results:

> SQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as p50...'

Comment: Q: Don't you need to specify a partition? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/percentile_cont/

Answer (score 2):

You can find db fiddle with example here https://dbfiddle.uk/RjmMGqBl.

Let's assume you have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (date_ DATE, count INT);
```

With records:

```
insert into test values ("2023-01-01", 10);
insert into test values ("2023-01-01", 17);
insert into test values ("2023-01-01", 20);
insert into test values ("2023-02-01", 13);
insert into test values ("2023-02-01", 13);
insert into test values ("2023-02-01", 14);
```

Then to get desired result your `select` statement should like this:

```
select distinct date_, 
  percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY count) OVER (PARTITION BY date_) AS p50
from test;
```

Comment: @lchow -  Anton Tokmakov is correct.  You apparently just forgot  the `OVER (PARTITION BY date_)` part of the clause.  Please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" this response.